# What's the perfect solution to implement title="<?php echo $title?>"

Tags: php, html

My current solution will suck sometimes

**EDIT**

For those who don't understand,see this example:

```
<a title="<?php echo 'test';?>" >...
```

Comment: With this little detail given, don't expect any answers.

Comment: Can you describe what it does when it doesn't work properly?

Comment: Or atleast what it's supposed to do when it does work properly?

Comment: So what's wrong with your example? Is the problem with quotation marks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a title="<?php echo htmlentities($title); ?>">
```

Comment: Why `htmlentities` and not `htmlspecialchars`?

Comment: Oh, just because that's what I'm accustomed to since it also converts scandinavian characters to entities.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're outputting to HTML, you need to convert special characters to HTML entities so you won't have any collisions with the HTML and your actual content.

In your example, (I think) you're trying to say that `<a title="<? echo 'test"'; ?>">`, and there would be a problem because of the extra quotation marks.

So you simply convert them to the proper `&quot;`, with the PHP function [`htmlspecialchars`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php):

`<a title="<? echo htmlspecialchars('test"'); ?>">`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a template engine, like Smarty.

But I prefer my own little tricks. I actually use globals, in a config file where I setup site wide variables, and constants.

e.g.

```
$title = 'My site';
$keywords = 'my site';
$description = 'welcome';
$javascript = array('jquery.js', ...);
$css = array('default.css');

define('SITE_URL', 'http://localhost/');
define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__));
...
```

My template will write out a HTML using the above variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a title="<?php echo 'test'; ?>">
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I can only give general information with that little.  The best I can say is that if you're inserting PHP variable values into HTML, you probably want to be outputting using the built-in templating.

```
echo <<<TEMPLATE
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" title="{$title}">Stackoverflow</a>
TEMPLATE;
```

This is much more clear and easier to manage.